# How to query price with different date

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently making a hotel reservation system and wondering how can I query price column in my tbl_prices table.

Here's how my table looks like:

```
id          date_from          date_to         price          is_default
1           00-00-0000         00-00-0000      $95               1
2           05-25-2012         05-29-2012      $100              0
3           06-20-2012         06-24-2012      $90               0
```

The first row is a default price. So if somebody reserve a date that is not in row 2 and 3 the price is $95. But if the reservation date fall on 2nd and 3rd row then the price should be $100 or $90.

Example if guest want to check in from 5-24-2012 to 5-26-2012 then the price should be

1st day = $95
2nd day = $100

5-26-2012 will not be charge because it is a checkout date.

Answer (score 0):

A very straight forward solution can be this:

`$from = 5-24-2012` and `$till = 5-26-2012`

```
select price, date_to from my_table where date_from <= $from 
ORDER BY date_from ASC LIMIT 1
```

Then probably you can make a check between date_to (received by this query) and $till.

```
if($till <= $date_to) {
    // total cost is price * no. of days of stay
}
else {
   // repeat above query, this time with date_to parameter in where clause
   // total cost is price1 * no. of days in 1st range + .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you query once for every day, there is only one default and there are no overlapping periods for prices:

```
SELECT price FROM tbl_prices
WHERE ($input_date >= date_from AND $input_date <= date_to) 
      OR is_default = 1
ORDER BY is_default
LIMIT 1
```